# Should paging through a list be stored in browser history for a SPA?

Tags: browser, history

I have a single page application (SPA) and currently paging through a list of items does not add items to the browser history. So you have a single entry in history for when you initially navigate to the list but no additional history for each page you view. Then if you view the details of an item on page 3 of the list and then hit `back` you will return to the first page of the list, not the third.

I figure the answer is yes but am putting this one out there for the community to advise.

---

FYI:

In my particular case I am using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and my `ngClick` callback uses `$http` to `GET` the paged results but could easily rearrange to have the `href` in the pager view point to an equivalent `url`.

Comment: Are you talking about adding pages to the browser history for things other than page loads? There'd be a UX question there. It's difficult to understand what exactly your question is at the moment.

Comment: @Brendon - I've reworded the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of web browsers, perception of history is literal and user expects to see the same page and scrolled to the same point on the page where he had left. If you are not storing paging in the history, your users are likely to wander that what is happening and why one back button took him 3 pages back.

Comment: A lot of Android apps make this mistake.